# Django 2.1 Token matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I've been trying to implement user authenitication in Django using `rest_framework.authtoken` as in [this guide](https://iheanyi.com/journal/user-registration-authentication-with-django-django-rest-framework-react-and-redux/). My test cases, which test for a range of different errors that could arise while a user logs in, are working properly before access tokens are introduced into the code.

For some reason, when I add in a check for the token returned in an Http response, I get the error:

`rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token.DoesNotExist: Token matching query does not exist.`

I've added in all of the relevant imports that should be needed to check for tokens so **could there be a function that was relocated to a different library in one of the more recent django versions? What might be causing the issue?**

**test.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse 
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class AccountsTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # We want to go ahead and originally create a user. 
        self.test_user = User.objects.create_user('testuser', 'test@example.com', 'testpassword')
        print('test user:' + str(self.test_user))

        # URL for creating an account.
        self.create_url = reverse('account-create')

    def test_create_user(self):
        """
        Ensure we can create a new user and a valid token is created with it.
        """
        data = {
                'username': 'foobar',
                'email': 'foobar@example.com',
                'password': 'somepassword'
                }

        response = self.client.post(self.create_url , data, format='json')
        user = User.objects.latest('id')

        token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['token'], token.key)
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from accounts.serializers import UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class UserCreate(APIView):
    """ 
    Creates the user. 
    """

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
                json = serializer.data
                json['token'] = token.key
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #third party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
}
```

Comment: Did the `user` instance created successfully.,  does this test pass `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)`

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan No, it fails with `AssertionError: 401 != 201`. For some reason, the token authentication is not working properly but all of the tests were working before the token authentication was added.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan Actually, the tests pass when I remove  `'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),`. How can I get the authentication to work along with the permissions.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was able to get pass the error using `.get_or_create`, instead of just `.get`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your settings file has the following permission class, it will applicable for all the views which extend `APIView`

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ( 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly', )
```

So set the `default config as same`., override it by setting `permission_classes` attribute in `APIView` like follow.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
class UserCreate(APIView):
     permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your code and it's working now.

```
class AccountsTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.User = get_user_model()
        self.user = self.User.objects.create_user(
            email='first@user.com',
            password='foo',
            name='Adam',
            lastname='First',
        )
        print('created test user:' + str(self.user))

    def test_create_and_login_user(self):
        """
        Тестируем:
        1) Создание юзера
        2) Авторизацию
        3) Сверяем токены
        """
        create_url = reverse('create_user')
        login_url = reverse('login')

        # ТЕСТ-1: создаем пользователя
        create_data = {
            'email': 'foobar@example.com',
            'password': 'somepassword',
            'name': 'Adam',
            'lastname': 'First',
        }
        response = self.client.post(create_url, create_data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.status_code)

        # ТЕСТ-2: авторизовываемся чтобы server создал токен для клиента
        login_data = {
            'email': 'foobar@example.com',
            'password': 'somepassword',
        }
        # после авторизации забираем ответ где хранится токен
        response = self.client.post(login_url, login_data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertIn('auth_token', response.data)
        # self.assertTrue(False, msg=response.data)

        # ТЕСТ-3: получаем id последнего зарегистрированного
        # пользователя и сверяем с тем что был в response
        user = self.User.objects.latest('id')
        # получаем его токен
        token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['auth_token'], token.key)
```